# Max-width on media query doesn't work for a lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, responsive-design

Having a custom LWC now I need to make it responsive, so I'm adding a media query `@media screen and (max-width : 480px)`

This doesn't work, If I change `max-width` to `max-device-width` it works, but I want to use only `max-width` as the max-device-width will soon be deprecated.

Any help on how to use media queries on LWC ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Below is how you can target `p` element and `max-width` or `min-width`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    p {
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    p {
        background: blue;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

2. It is preferable to use [device-size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/specification) in LWC. Below is how it behaves:

- `size` is mandatory when you want custom responsive design by defining **large, mediu and small**.
- `size` starts from **0** width.
- When you just give `size` and `medium-device-size`, *size* will be taken for ***0 to medium*** width. Sample is with small or large.
- `small` is actually the horizontal view for almost all mobiles - this is very important point. Therefore `size` should be  maximum parts always to accommodate mobile vertical view.

### Below are the examples:

1. Consider below code:

```html
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <lightning-layout-item size="4" small-device-size="12">
            ... content ...
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="4" small-device-size="12">
            ... content ...
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="4" small-device-size="12">
            ... content ...
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
```

This will render 3 columns in mobile vertical view and single column in mobile horizontal view. So, you need `size` to be maximum parts of all device sizes always - which means `12` in this case.

2. For below example:

```html
<lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="4">
    ... content ...
</lightning-layout-item>
<lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="4">
    ... content ...
</lightning-layout-item>
<lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="4">
    ... content ...
</lightning-layout-item>
```

For big screens, you get 3 columns and for any device less it will be single column

3. For below example:

```html
<lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="4" medium-device-size="6" small-device-size="12">
    ... content ...
</lightning-layout-item>
<lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="4" medium-device-size="6" small-device-size="12">
    ... content ...
</lightning-layout-item>
```

This is straight forward - mobile vertical or horizontal view will have single columns. Medium devices like pads will have 2 columns and desktops will have 3 columns.